# How to use print inside a single liner for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have a line of code , where i want to use **print(i)** to see the last value of **i**, is it possible? :

```
tag = [i.text.rstrip(),print(i) for i in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("tbody") ]
```

apparntly this is a **syntax error**

Comment: The syntax should be fine for Python 3, but not for 2. Showcus the full error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the right way to use List comprehension for printing

```
tag = []
for i in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("tbody"):
    tag.append(i.text.rstrip())
    print(i)
```

OR

```
tag = [i.text.rstrip() for i in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("tbody") ]
print(tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are doing this just for debugging.
In this case you can build tuples for each stripped and raw element:

```
l = ['this', 'is ', 'some', 'text ']
print([(i.rstrip(), i) for i in l])
>> [('this', 'this'), ('is', 'is '), ('some', 'some'), ('text', 'text ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say there are 7 values so the last one is 7
Print LISTNAME(7)
If there's only 3 values
Print LISTNAME(9)

So you should be able to do a command
Lastvalue = (a command that finds how many values are in the liat)
Print LISTNAME(Lastvalue)